# Many-to-One relationships in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I'm having trouble with Many-to-One relationships between my SQLAlchemy models. The relationship between `ChangeOrder` (many) and `Contract` (one) is fine, but the one between `LineItem` (many) and `ChangeOrder` (one) isn't working.

I've tried both approaches suggested in the [basic relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one) docs and both fail for the `LineItem` to `ChangeOrder` relationship.

```
# using back_populates
class Contract(Base):
    __tablename__ = "contract"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    change_orders = relationship("ChangeOrder", back_populates="contract")


class ChangeOrder(Base):
    __tablename__ = "changeorder"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    line_items = relationship("LineItem", back_populates="change_order")
    contract_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("contract.id"))
    contract = relationship("Contract", back_populates="change_orders")


class LineItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = "lineitem"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    change_order_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("changeorder.id"))
    change_order = relationship("ChangeOrder", back_populates="line_items")


def test_insert_change_order(db_session, item):
    c = Contract()
    db_session.add(c)
    db_session.commit()
    co = ChangeOrder(contract_id=c.id)
    db_session.add(co)
    db_session.commit()
    row = db_session.query(Contract).get(c.id)
    assert len(row.change_orders) == 1  # this Many-to-One works
    li = LineItem(change_order_id=co.id)
    db_session.add(li)
    db_session.commit()
    row = db_session.query(ChangeOrder).get(co.id)
    assert len(row.line_items) == 1  # this Many-to-One does not
```

I also tried the `backref` approach, but it has the same problem.

```
# using backref
class LineItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = "lineitem"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    change_order_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("changeorder.id"))
    change_order = relationship("ChangeOrder", backref="line_items")


class ChangeOrder(Base):
    __tablename__ = "changeorder"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    contract_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("contract.id"))
    contract = relationship("Contract", backref="change_orders")


class Contract(Base):
    __tablename__ = "contract"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

conftest.py

```
import pytest
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from frontend.app import app


@pytest.fixture
def testapp():
    db = SQLAlchemy()
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ECHO"] = True
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        yield app
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def database():
    db = SQLAlchemy()
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        yield db


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def _db(database):
    return database
```

Comment: Hi Jamie, both versions of your code are working for me. Are there any other specifics to your environment? Any session level configurations? If you set `echo=True` on your `engine` do all of the queries look right?

Comment: Also, if you set `use_list=False` on the one side of the relationship your relationship attribute will either be `None` or `object` as opposed to `[]` or `[object]` which saves you from having to index out an object from a single length list every time you want to use it. Unrelated to your problem but just thought I'd mention.

Comment: Queries look fine to me. I've made sure all my migrations are up to date. Testing is using `pytest-flask-sqlalchemy` which provides the `db_session` and I've added my `conftest.py` to the question

Comment: Sorry but I can't see where your original example and that conftest file intersect. All I did was put at the bottom of your original examples engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True); Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine); Base.metadata.drop_all(engine); Base.metadata.create_all(engine); test_insert_change_order(Session(), None)

Comment: Ok, I guess it's some problem in my testing setup then. I'll dig into that